# How to fix the Battery drain issue of my app

Tags: android, batterymanager

**Problem facing & my app functionalities**

I have an application which perform the Media projection for 24 hours in background  and my app has  only services which is collecting the users keystrokes,call history ,message,chrome history , location( observes only if location changes ) and send to  server Via API , these  all are runs through services so if we kill the app also it will be runs in background through services , the problem is ,it drains the battery very much which means for every 30  minutes  apoximatiely 20 - 25  percentage of battery drains , i accept that lot of services is running in background so it cause the battery drains but still any chance to reduce the battery drainage?

**What i Tried**

i read many answers in stackoverflow and implemneted like changing the CPU usage functionalities to Default Coroutines thread  but this method not worked for me then no answer helped me to solve this

I am strucked on this, any solution that may be helpfull to solve this  issue ? please share your ideas as answers , thanks in advance